# can't import IMG_VAR from './images/name.jpg' with babel / React / Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-isomorphic-tools

**Background (possibly irrelevent)**: I have a large react project I'm changing gulp -> webpack. It's isomorphic so I'm using webpack-isomorphic-tools.

So I have this line which no longer works:

`const CANDLE_JPG = require('./assets/candle.jpg');` which returns error:

> .assets/candle.jpg should not be assigned to variable.

But if I change it to:

`import CANDLE_JPG from './assets/candle.jpg'` I get the error:

> ./assets/candle.jpg should not be imported using default imports.

**Thoughts**: I believe it could be some issue with babel compilation, but I'm not sure. I've used `require('babel-register')` and my ".bablerc" contains presets `es2015`, `react`, and `stage-0` and includes plugins `transform-runtime`,  and `react-hot-loader/babel`.

File Loader:

```
const fileLoader = {
  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
  exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.hbs$/, /\.json$/],
  options: {
    name: 'assets/images/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    emitFile: true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us your webpack configuration?
You probably need to use an image loader like  [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)  then use :

```
import CANDLE_JPG from './assets/candle.jpg'
```

and configure webpack like this:

```
{
     test: /\.(gif|png|jpg)$/,
     exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/'),
     use: [
          'file-loader',
           {
               loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
               options: {
                   bypassOnDebug: true,
                }
            }
      ],
}
```

Comment: Hey @whoknows, I just added my code, I will try to add yours and see what happens

Comment: I was unsuccessful with adding that data, still received the same error

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-isomorphic-tools#configuration-examples   heres a sample of webpack-isomorphic-tools configuration for jpg. It's natively supported with no further configuration.

Comment: You are correct, it is natively supported, however my config seems to still cause it to break. I'm comparing to https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example to try to solve my issue